# My rails app use mysql database and AR-ORM, but I want impressionist single use MongoDB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am using [impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem

In my rails app I am using both mysql database and AR-ORM, but I want to use impressionist only for MongoDB.

Comment: Have you read official [docs](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist#are-you-using-mongoid) ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to change your app, you'll need to swap out your use of ActiveRecord for something specific to MongoDB. It appears [from the documentation](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist#are-you-using-mongoid) that Impressionist only supports the use of `mongoid`, so if you [configure your app for using `mongoid` according to their docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#configuration) after adding it to your Gemfile, you should be able to use Impressionist with it.